# python - generating millions of json data

Tags: python, json, out-of-memory, pypy, faker

I need some dummy data in json format, to use in another project. I'm currently using the `Faker` package in the code below:

```
from json import dumps
from faker import Faker
import collections

database = []
filename = '1M'
length   = 1000000
fake     = Faker() # <--- Forgot this

for x in range(length):
    database.append(collections.OrderedDict([
        ('last_name', fake.last_name()),
        ('first_name', fake.first_name()),
        ('street_address', fake.street_address()),
        ('email', fake.email())
    ]))

with open('%s.json' % filename, 'w') as output:
    output.write(dumps(database, indent=4))
print "Done."
```

This code works, but it's very slow. I tried `PyPy`, and I was blown away by the results. I'm currently able to generate a json file with 1 million data, which is about 220mb, in ~600 seconds. The problem is when I try to go further, for example, 2 millions data, which I would expect it to finish in ~1200 seconds, the script runs beyond this time and I'm greeted by this exception `MemoryError` with no explanation on why it occurred, I believe it has something to with `PYPY_GC_MAX`, but again a 2M file should weight ~440mb.

While trying to fix this issue, I'm still looking a way to squeeze the generation time even more. I've tried list comprehension, `map()`, the results were the same as for loop.

Thanks

Comment: Which python you use?

Comment: Python 2.7.12 32bits

Comment: Do you need to use an `OrderedDict`? That probably increases the time.

Comment: The other project requires that order :(

Comment: Are you sure? JSON dicts don't have a concept of order, if this is the case then the other project is likely broken.

Comment: In the other project, I have to parse JSON manually, no external libraries are allowed. Thankfully it's limited to strings.

Comment: What about using a CSV instead of JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go out-of-memory because you first generate the whole database first, and then dump the database. A more memory-friendy way would be to generate the dict entries on the fly. A better way would be to use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) which makes the entries on the fly.

```
def fake_person_generator(length):
    for x in range(length):  # xrange in Python 2.7
        yield OrderedDict([
            ('last_name', 'lastname_%i' % x),
            ('first_name', 'firstname_%i' % x),
            ('street_address', 'adress_%i' % x),
            ('email', 'email_%i' % x)])
```

Combined with Alex Hall's answer this should reduce the memory need dramatically.

I don't know the json-module so well, but the writing would be something like:

```
length = 1000000
fpg = fake_person_generator(length)
with open('%s.json' % filename, 'w') as output:
    for person in fpg:
        json.dump(person, output)
print "Done."
```

Comment: you don't pass the generator directly, but iterate over it. Expanded on it in my answer.

Comment: OP's current code produces a JSON array, so this will produce a different output (although admittedly this form might be the better way to go). To produce a list you could, for example, manually write in extra commas and square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use `OrderedDict`: JSON format may not (and will not) save order of items. Even if order will be saved in the file - it will breaks when another project will parse that file.

You just need to use `dict`. Also it will be much more faster.

To save the order of items you should explicitly preserve the index of an each element. Like this:

```
from json import dumps
from faker import Faker
import collections
import json

def fake_person_generator(length, fake):
    for x in range(length):  # xrange in Python 2.7
        yield {'last_name': fake.last_name(),
               'first_name': fake.first_name(),
               'street_address': fake.street_address(),
               'email': fake.email(),
               'index': x}

database = []
filename = '1M'
length   = 1000000
fake     = Faker() # <--- Forgot this
fpg = fake_person_generator(length, fake)
with open('%s.json' % filename, 'w') as output:
    output.write('[')  # to made json file valid according to JSON format
    for person in fpg:
        json.dump(person, output)
    output.write(']')  # to made json file valid according to JSON format
print "Done."
```

Comment: I'm aware that the order is not kept, since I have to start from scratch, to make my life easier I fixed the order to have a sort of template to use.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `output.write(json.dumps(database))`, use `json.dump(database, output)` to iteratively write the JSON to file without constructing a large string in memory.

Comment: It bumped up the generating time slightly. I'll try it now with 2M.

Comment: :( `MemoryError` [Image](http://i.imgur.com/lM4TxgC.png) from Task Manager before the exception.

Comment: @Be0wulf the problem at this stage is not the JSON, but the giant list! See Maarten's answer and my comment.